# Does Swift support pattern matching?

Tags: swift, recursion, pattern-matching

Does swift supportt pattern matching ?

```
func sum(_ lst: [Int]) -> Int {
    guard !lst.isEmpty else {
        return 0
    }

    return lst.first! + sum(Array(lst.dropFirst()))
}
```

Could this function be rewritten using pattern matching ?

Comment: Just use `lst.reduce(0, +)`, no guard needed

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "pattern matching"? Swift has support for a concept like this, but that support doesn't seem to be fit for the code you posted. Can you give mode details about your understanding of the concept?

Answer (score 1):

> Does swift supportt pattern matching ?

Yes. There's a whole section called [Patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html) in the language reference.

> Could this function be rewritten using pattern matching ?

I guess you mean you want to match the "first" element and the "rest" of the elements of the list, like you do in Haskell? Yes, you can do:

```
func sum(_ lst: [Int]) -> Int
{
    if case let (first?, rest) = (lst.first, Array(lst.dropFirst())) {
        return first + sum(rest)
    }
    return 0
}
```

This matches the expression `(lst.first, Array(lst.dropFirst()))` against a [value binding pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID422), which has a few subpatterns, including a [tuple pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID423), [identifier patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID421), and an [optional pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID520).

However, this is not idiomatic (and not very efficient either).

Rather than writing this recursively, which will overflow the stack when the array is long, you should use `reduce`.

```
func sum(_ lst: [Int]) -> Int
{
    lst.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Taking this one step further, we can write this in an extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func sum() -> Element
    {
        reduce(.zero, +)
    }
}

// Usage:
[1, 2, 3, 4].sum() // returns 10
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and answers the question well. But what is the benifit of using an extension to write this piece of code?

Comment: @CassandraTrotter it allows you to write `someArray.sum()` rather than `sum(someArray)`. It might not make so much of an actual difference in this case, but it is idiomatic in Swift to write such utilities that operate on a type as extensions of that type.